# how to insert data into existing value in localstorage

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a `users` key / value saved in local storage looking like this:

```
users = {
    name: "John",
    email: "jsmith@gmail.com",
    car: []
}
```

as seen `car` in the users object is empty.

This is a useState that has a default value of `0` which is used later to get the existing values in localstorage.

```
const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
```

This useState has car features that need to be updated in localstorage.

```
const [car, setCar] = useState([{
        make: "Lamborghini",
        year: "2020",
        color: "Yellow"
}]);
```

My problem is with this function, when I pass in the `car` parameter which is the state value from above, and I get the index value from localstorage which returns correctly the data in storage.

```
function setCar(car) {
    const cars = getCarsFromStorage(index);
    localStorage.setItem("users", JSON.stringify({index, cars: car}));
}
```

When I setItem in localstorage to the useState value, the local storage looks like this:

```
users = {
    index: 0
    cars: [{
        make: "Lamborghini",
        year: "2020",
        color: "Yellow"
    }]
}
```

Which is not what I want it to look like, instead should look like this:

```
users = {
    name: "John",
    email: "jsmith@gmail.com",
    car: [{
        make: "Lamborghini",
        year: "2020",
        color: "Yellow"
    }]
}
```

Would this be possible to do, if so how would I approach this? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You are explicitly creating the object `{index, cars: car}`, so why are you surprised now that that's what you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`localStorage.setItem("users", DATA)` All in **DATA** will replace what you have in localStorage. **"users"** is the key **DATA** is the value.

What you need to do is to get what you have in the localStorage then update values.

Something like that:

```js
function setCar(car) {
    //const cars = getCarsFromStorage(index); // no need this line

    const newDataUsers = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("users"));
    newDataUsers.cars = [cars,...newDataUsers.cars];
    localStorage.setItem("users", JSON.stringify(newDataUsers));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to get complete users object from localStorage and deserialize it

```
let oldObj = localStorage.getItem("users");
oldObj = JSON.parse(oldObj);
localStorage.setItem("users", JSON.stringify({...oldObj, cars: car}));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the spread operator `...` to spread all the existing values into the same object along with the new car details.

```js
let users = {
  name: "someone",
  email: "abc@example.com",
  car: []
};
console.log("before:", users);

// get car details [replace with localstorage fetch]
const car = {
  make: "Lambo",
  year: "2009",
}

users = { ...users,
  car: [...users.car, car]
}

// get another car details [replace with localstoarge fetch]
const car2 = {
  make: "bmw",
  year: "2020",
}

users = { ...users,
  car: [...users.car, car2]
}

// after adding 2 cars
console.log("after:", users);
```